# 2003 Rav4 Reverse light switch

Tags: electrical, toyota, rav4, switches

Can anyone tell me how to replace the reverse light switch on the 2003 Rav4?  I found it on the trans housing, but I can't get a socket  on it since it is buried kind of under the ?starter motor? and the coil.  Looks like I'd have to remove some sort of wiring plastic stiffener and try and bend the wire harness out of the way. The harness is REALLY stiff.  There also doesn't appear to be enough room to swing a wrench (only a couple of degrees of clearance.

Comment: Can you take a picture? You may just have to buckle down and remove whatever you have to, to get to the range switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it appears to require a socket and a 1/2" extension bar - fairly long - 15" or so.  Tried using a 20", 3/8" bar and it seemed to twist a bit so I couldn't get torque to the socket all that cleanly.  Note that the plastic stiffener covers the HOT lead to the starter motor and that you can easily ground out if you touch it accidentally (don't ask how I know this).  MAKE SURE TO DISCONNECT THE BATTERY.  Note that it takes a LOT of torque and penetrating oil to break the switch free.